# Why fsize variable is cleared if global?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to calculate the shannon entropy of a file in python.

So, I have written the following code to achieve this.
But  it doesn't work as expected.

I think all is right, but the fsize variable is cleared.

I don't understand why because it holds global scope.

Can you give a hand or explanation ?

Thanks

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import os
import math


def get_chunks(file_size, chunk_size = 4096):

    chunk_start = 0

    while chunk_start + chunk_size < file_size:
        yield(chunk_start, chunk_size)
        chunk_start += chunk_size

    final_chunk_size = file_size - chunk_start
    yield(chunk_start, final_chunk_size)


def read_file_chunked(file_path):

    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    fsize = file_size # <------------------------------this var
    print('File size: {}'.format(file_size))

    with open(file_path,'rb') as file_:

        progress = 0

        for chunk_start, chunk_size in get_chunks(file_size):

            file_chunk = file_.read(chunk_size)

            # byte count
            for b in file_chunk:
                freqs[ord(b)]+=1

            progress += len(file_chunk)
            print '{0} of {1} bytes read ({2}%)'.format( progress, file_size, int(progress / file_size * 100))

        #calculate the frequency of each byte
        for idx, f in enumerate(freqs):
            freqs[idx] = float(f / file_size)
        print



freqs = [0] * 256
fsize = 0 #<------------------ this var


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage entropy [file]"
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    read_file_chunked(sys.argv[1])

    # print byte frequencies
    for idx,f in enumerate(freqs):
        print hex(idx),f

    # calculate Shannon entropy
    ent = 0.0    
    for f in freqs:
        if f > 0:
            ent += f * math.log(f,2)
    ent = -ent

    print 'Shannon entropy ( min bits per byte-character )'
    print ent
    print
    print 'Min possible file size assuming max compression efficiency'
    print (ent * fsize), ' in bits' #------------------- here fsize is 0
    print (ent * fsize) / 8, ' in bytes' #-------------- here fsize is 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `read_file_chunked` function you are creating a new variable `fsize` within the scope of the function, you don't modify your global variable at all. Consider the following demonstration:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> def foo():
...     x = 1
... 
>>> foo()
>>> x
0
```

What you are missing to make that piece of code work the way you intend to is the `global` keyword:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> def foo():
...     global x
...     x = 1
... 
>>> foo()
>>> x
1
```

Having said that I question your usage of the global variable. Why don't you just `return` `fsize` from your function?

Answer (score 2):

assigning to `fsize` in `read_file_chunked` creates a new local variable that is deleted when the function returns. In order to assign to the global variable `fsize`, declare it explicitly as such:

```
def read_file_chunked(file_path):
    global fsize
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    fsize = file_size # <------------------------------this var
```

Alternatively, have `read_file_chunked` return the file size.

Comment: why ?  freqs variable is assigned inside and works as expected. Is not re-created.

Comment: @ppk you are never reassigning `freqs` in the function, you just modify its content by indexing into it.